# How to configure/run gradle to build and assemble release type running all unit tests first

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

When I run

```
./gradlew clean assembleRelease
```

my binaries are built, but the unit tests do not run.

When I run

```
./gradlew clean build
```

all binaries are built and all unit tests are run, twice... once for debug and once for release.

How can I achieve what 'clean build' does but only for the release buildType?

Context: The main problem I am trying to solve is what is the proper way to configure a jenkins job to build assemble and run all unit tests for the RELEASE buildType only.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have solved this for now is by adding this code block to the bottom of build.gradle in each module of my project:

```
project.tasks.assembleRelease.dependsOn {
    project.tasks.findAll { task ->
        task.name.startsWith('testRelease')
    }
}
```

This does what I need it to do, such that when our jenkins server job runs:

```
clean assembleRelease
```

All the release unit tests are run and the artifacts are all created.

Not sure if this is the best/cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
gradlew clean check assembleRelease
```

This cleans and verifies (includes running tests) for all subprojects (even plain java ones) and then assembles only the `release` `buildType`, i.e. dexing and signing is only done as specified in the `release` closure.

I'm not sure if that's the cleanest solution, either. Still, it does not append boilerplate to `build.gradle` files and its is faster than running the `clean build` tasks.

A good overview over gradle's anchor tasks `assemble`, `check` and `build` is provided by the [Gradle Plugin User Guide](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Tasks).